# aligning nested div's left and right inside container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div which is as wide as the page and has two div's inside it, one which is aligned left and one aligned right. Its' turning out to be a lot more difficult than I expected. With the code below, both div's align left. I have made a [jsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTRPA/) to demonstrate the problem. Thanks for reading.

```
<style>

#container{
            border:1px solid;
}

#left{
       text-align:left;
       border:1px solid red;
       display:table-cell;
}

#right{
       text-align:right;
       border:1px solid blue;
       display:table-cell;
}

</style>

<body>

  <div id = "container">
    <div id = "left">far left</div>
    <div id = "right">far right</div>
  </div>   

</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to use floating elements or absolute positioning in general for something like this.
It's an approach that should've stopped along with using tables for general layouts.

[**Sample Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7KCy7/)

CSS:

```
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#container > div {
    display: table-cell;
}

.right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <p>Left</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>Right</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The lack of floats is a great thing. Floats are high-maintenance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
float: left
```

and

```
float: right
```

on the divs.

A cooler way of aligning things is to use

```
display:flex
```

on the container, but you'll have to check the browser compatibility for that I'm afraid.

Comment: I think the link you posted is to the original jsFiddle.

Comment: Sorry. made a mistake while copy-pasting.